# Combine 3 array and write to text file

Tags: bash

Below is the code i written to get individual columns in array from a command

```
while read -r var
do
      MemModCondHP=`command`
      printf '%s\n' "$MemModCondHP" >> ${var}_MemModCondHP.txt
      HPSlNoFromMemModCond=`cat ${var}_MemModCondHP.txt | cut -d= -f1`  
      HPStatus=`cat ${var}_MemModCondHP.txt | cut -d= -f2`
done < HP_S_List.txt
```

i have the server name in `$var` and i am doing this for a list of servers.

Now i need to create a text file like below from the above data

```
sevrername;HPSlNoFromMemModCond1;HPStatus1
sevrername;HPSlNoFromMemModCond2;HPStatus2
sevrername;HPSlNoFromMemModCond3;HPStatus3
```

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an echo line to your script. For this example I set it to write `output.csv`:

```
while read -r var
do
      MemModCondHP=`command`
      printf '%s\n' "$MemModCondHP" >> ${var}_MemModCondHP.txt
      HPSlNoFromMemModCond=`cat ${var}_MemModCondHP.txt | cut -d= -f1`  
      HPStatus=`cat ${var}_MemModCondHP.txt | cut -d= -f2`

      echo "${var};${HPSlNoFromMemModCond};${HPStatus}" > output.csv

done < HP_S_List.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
But it is only printing the `${var}` value like below
`1.5.8.4
1.5.8.5
1.5.8.6
1.5.8.7
1.5.8.8;`